# CD4011BPWR Button Press Logic NAND IC

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

[image]

During testing on my pcb I am running into a couple of problems the first issue is with either my momentary switch or my MOSFET Q4 – PMV30XPEA. For my switch design, I have implemented Fig. 5 on [MOSAIC DOCUMENTATION WEB Latch and Toggle power circuits](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch) article, which is quick press on – 3 sec press off. During testing, I have had to hold the switch down for about 5 seconds before it turns off. I am using the switch – KSS221GLFS.

The upper right hand side is where the switch and Q4 & Q5 is located. I'm using a 3.6V LiPo and boosting it to 5V DC/DC converter.

Do any of you have any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: I would advise against using the CD4011 in this application. You will need something with Schmitt trigger inputs if you are wanting to handle edges that slow. That being said, the CD series is antiquated enough that it may not be a problem.

Comment: Where do you see the CD4011?

Comment: It's the NAND gate in your first image.

Comment: why do you advise against CD4011?

Comment: Without Schmitt trigger inputs, it will draw an excessive amount of power. Logic inputs generally work best with fast-switching inputs, and the "shark fin" waveform of an RC circuit generally very slow (3-7 seconds in your case).

Comment: What type of capacitor are C29 and C30?

Comment: C-29,  C-30 are Multilayer Ceramic Capacitors - 81-GRT188R61H105KE3D

Comment: It's also much easier to understand the intention of the circuit if you use the NAND gate symbols rather than a 14-pin chip. Without the symbols one would have to be familiar with the chip pinout or else look it up to figure out what the circuit is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem(s)

There are several issues with your CD4011-based design.

- Digital chips do not have a well-defined switching thresholds. V<sub>IH</sub> and V<sub>IL</sub> set upper and lower limits, but the actual switching threshold varies, and is usually somewhere in between.
- CMOS logic chips do not like slow-transitioning signals. They tend to draw excessive amounts of power when a signal slowly passes through the threshold.
- Even if you used a chip with Schmitt trigger inputs like the [CD4093B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4093b.pdf), both the high and low thresholds (V<sub>P</sub> and V<sub>N</sub>) as well as the hysteresis voltage (V<sub>H</sub>) vary significantly from chip to chip.
- All logic thresholds change as the supply voltage changes. In this case, you can expect the supply voltage to vary between 4V (fully charged) and 2.9V (discharged).
- A purely digital solution would be significantly more complex.

---

### A Solution

This is one of the rare instances in which I would actually recommend using a 555 timer. However, you can't use a "generic" bipolar 555 (like the NE555), since it will not operate at a low enough voltage. Instead, you need a CMOS variant such as the [MIC1555](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005730A.pdf), [TLC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf), or [LMC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf), all of which can operate over a wide voltage range and consume *much* less power than a bipolar 555 (100μA vs. 5mA).

If you look at the schematic below, you will see the simplified internals of a CMOS 555 timer. First, note that the thresholds are defined to be at 1/3 (TRIG) and 2/3 (THRES) of the supply voltage, thanks to the three well-matched series resistors. This is convenient since the time constant of an RC circuit is (roughly) the time it takes to rise or decay to/from 2/3 of the input (battery) voltage.

[image: CMOS 555 simplified schematic]

There is also one critical detail that should be taken into account: TRIG overrides THRES, so it is preferable to use TRIG to detect a turn off condition. This will also prevent the circuit from automatically turning on during power up. In order to get the timing right, I used two RC circuits.

- Turn-off: a 3.3μF capacitor (I recommend Tantalum due to its low leakage and temperature stability) in series with a 1MΩ resistor produces a time constant of ~3s, and decays to 1/3 of the supply voltage when the button is pressed.
- Turn-on: a 100nF capacitor in series with a 1MΩ resistor produces a time constant of 100ms, enough to provide adequate adequate debouncing. This prevents the power from turning back on after you release the button. Note that a small N-channel MOSFET (such as the 2N7002 or BSS138) is required in order to invert the switch signal.

The output of the 555 is active-low in this case, and can directly drive your series pass transistor (the PMV30XPEA).

[image: Press-on-hold-off 555 timer circuit]

Here's an interactive [simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.001+11.558428452718767+50+5+50%0Ar+48+112+48+192+0+1000%0Ac+176+240+176+304+0+0.0000032999999999999997+3.5925645426588413%0Ar+176+240+48+240+0+1000000%0Aw+48+240+48+192+0%0As+48+304+48+240+0+1+true%0Ag+48+304+48+320+0%0Ag+176+304+176+320+0%0Aw+176+240+336+240+0%0AR+48+112+48+80+0+0+40+3.6+0+0+0.5%0A207+336+176+336+160+4+TH%0A207+336+240+336+256+4+TR%0Aw+240+192+48+192+0%0Af+240+192+288+192+0+1.5+0.02%0Ag+288+208+288+320+0%0Aw+48+112+288+112+0%0Ar+288+112+288+176+0+1000000%0Aw+288+176+336+176+0%0A165+400+144+544+144+6+3.5999999640000007%0Aw+288+112+464+112+0%0Aw+336+240+400+240+0%0Aw+336+176+368+176+0%0Aw+368+176+368+272+0%0Aw+368+272+400+272+0%0Ag+496+304+496+320+0%0Aw+528+176+528+112+0%0Aw+528+112+464+112+0%0Aw+528+208+576+208+0%0Ac+368+272+368+336+0+1.0000000000000001e-7+0.00008571429735442369%0Ag+368+336+368+352+0%0Af+576+208+576+112+9+1+0.008%0Aw+528+112+560+112+0%0Ar+640+112+640+208+0+100%0Ag+640+208+640+224+0%0Aw+592+112+640+112+0%0Ao+9+64+0+4098+0.00030517578125+0.1+0+2+9+3%0Ao+10+64+0+4098+5+0.1+1+2+10+3%0A) of the circuit.

---

I actually built the circuit using a TLC555, and it draws ~180μA over the full 3-15V supply range. I did make one minor alteration: the 1kΩ resistor was replaced with a 100kΩ to prevent the circuit from drawing excessive current when the button was pressed.